# Populate select from database with php

Tags: php, mysql

Something is wrong with that code, i mean, it's not doing what i want it to.

```
<?php
     $con = mysql_connect($db_s, $db_u, $db_p);
     $db = mysql_select_db("saritur", $con);
     $query = "SELECT resumo FROM resumos";
     $res = mysql_query($query,$con);

     echo "<select name='usuario' id='usuario'>";
     while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) != null)
     {
     echo "<option value = '".$row['resumo']."'>".$row['resumo']."</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
     mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I'm new into PHP so that's already a problem, i got that code from another question in here but still won't work

Edit:

Ok guys i had a stupid problem, the variables $db_s, $db_u etc was on a include file, unfortunately i was not getting the values from it so i had to declare them on the main file and it's looking like this now:

```
<select name="resumo" id="usuario">
   <?php
   $db_u = 'phiter';
   $db_p = '****';
   $db_s = '127.0.0.1';

   $con = mysql_connect($db_s, $db_u, $db_p);
   $db = mysql_select_db("saritur", $con);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM resumos";

   $res = mysql_query($query,$con);
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
       {
           echo "<option value = '{$row['resumo']}'>{$row['resumo']}</option>";
       }

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
</select>
```

It is communicating with the database and the number of rows are the same as the number on the database, NICE! But it's all showing white blocks, there is nothing written on the options. I saw the error on page code, it says

> Notice: Undefined index: resumo in xxx on line *48*

WHYYYYYY

Another update:

Changed `mysql_fetch_row` into `mysql_fetch_array`, now it works

Comment: Nothing, it should populate a select box, but it isn't doing it.

Comment: The functions you are using are out of date for a start, are you following a very old tutorial?  Check the php.net reference pages for those functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.  Though that shouldn't really explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to access an error log, or have you see any errors appear on the page?   Have you successfully performed database queries using the connection?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong.  Beyond your other problems it uses deprecated code. You should probably stop using `mysql_` functions and look into prepared statements.   As for your specific problem, you are going back and forth between single and double quotes for variables. you should be consistent

Comment: @miken32, not as simple as that since this question has multiple issues. Wasn't only the undefined index one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have a gamble here that this is the only thing that is wrong...

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) != null)
```

change to

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)))
```

Why?   See the reference pages

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

mysql_fetch_row() returns a numerical array, whereas mysql_fetch_assoc returns a keyed array... which is how you're using it.

Alternatively you can keep using mysql_fetch_row() but then use $row[0] or reset($row) to access the first value.

Comment: WOW mysql_fetch_assoc fixed my new problem haha, thanks mate!

Comment: Note the warning on those links at the top of the page;  both functions are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_row